# PivotTable Filter shows old and new data in excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a PivotTable and the source is a Table (not a range of cells).

When I modify the source table, in the Pivot Table Filter I see both old and modified item.

For example, in one column I have street names and I change as below:
Old: **Heidelberger St.**
Modified to: **Heidelberger Street**

Now, in the PivotTable (after doing Refresh All), when I open the header filter, I see both "Heidelberger St." and "Heidelberger Street". Although the "Heidelberger St." results no data in the Pivot Table, but it is still there in the Filter list.

Does anyone know how can I remove the old data.

With so thanks,
Dio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in this website: [www.contextures.com](http://www.contextures.com/xlPivot04.html)

However, I summarize it here:

**Problem**: Old Items Remain in Pivot Field Dropdowns

**Solution**: Change Retain Items Setting in Excel 2010/2007

**Description**:

1. Right-click a cell in the pivot table
2. Click on PivotTable options
3. Click on the Data tab
4. In the Retain Items section, select None from the drop down list.
5. Click OK, then refresh the pivot table.

[image: Screenshot]

**Source**: http://www.contextures.com/xlPivot04.html